# Using single map in many layouts of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, map-frame

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

How can I have a single map and many layouts, each of them pointing to a different part of the map?

That is, when I finish a layout, I would like to "freeze" it and make a different one, that shows a different area of the map.

In this way I will have, map1, layout1, layout2, layout3, etc.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a map frame on each of your multiple layouts then changing the extent of each by activating them one at a time?

Comment: How many layouts do you need to make? If it's more than a handful, I would suggest using a single layout and inserting a map series based on either bookmark or a polygon layer that defines the extent of each map page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how many layouts you want to produce using the same map, there are a few different solutions. If you only need to show a few different areas of the same map, the simplest would be to create multiple map layouts, insert a map frame in each pointing to the same map, and then activate each map frame to set the extent.

If you have more than a handful of map layouts you want to create, I would suggest using a Map Series. To do that:

1. Create a new polygon layer and digitize polygons that correspond to the desired extent for each map layout.
   [image]
2. Insert a new layout in your project and add a map frame for your map. Then, click Insert > Map Series > Spatial. In the window that opens, select your map frame and set the polygon layer you created as the Layer. You can also change other optional settings for grouping, extents, etc. When you're done, click OK.
   [image]

[image]

3. A new Map Series Page will be created for each of your extent polygons. Assuming you don't want these polygons to show up in your exported map layouts, go back to your map and turn off visibility for that layer. To export, click Share > Export Layout. If you select PDF as the File Type, there will be additional options under a Map Series tab in the Layout pane to set how you want the pages exported (e.g., one pdf per page, or all pages in one pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it's the best solution, I'm going to try what you suggest.